# pandas: check if value exist groupby column

Tags: pandas, group-by

I want to check if the value unknown exist in the column place group by date if not i want to add row with value unknown, and 0 in the sum.

How should i do it please?

```
date        place     sum_
2021-07-04   NY       100
2021-07-04   LA       200
2021-07-04   MILAN    300
2021-07-04   PARIS    100
2021-07-05   NY       200
2021-07-05   LA       100
2021-07-05   MILAN    100
2021-07-05   PARIS    50
2021-07-05   unknown  200
```

**expected output**

```
date        place     sum_
2021-07-04   NY       100
2021-07-04   LA       200
2021-07-04   MILAN    300
2021-07-04   PARIS    100
2021-07-04   unknown   0
2021-07-05   NY       200
2021-07-05   LA       100
2021-07-05   MILAN    100
2021-07-05   PARIS    50
2021-07-05   unknown  200
```

Answer (score -1):

find the dates that have `unknown` & create a dataframe of unknowns to unite to the original frame

```py
has_unknown = df.groupby('date').apply(
  lambda x: any(x.place == 'unknown')
).rename('has_unknown').reset_index()
has_unknown['sum_'] = 0
has_unknown['place'] = 'unknown' 
out = pd.concat([df, has_unknown.loc[~has_unknown.has_unknown, ['date', 'place', 'sum_']]]
).sort_values(['date', 'place'])
```

```
# out looks like
         date    place  sum_
1  2021-07-04       LA   200
2  2021-07-04    MILAN   300
0  2021-07-04       NY   100
3  2021-07-04    PARIS   100
0  2021-07-04  unknown     0
5  2021-07-05       LA   100
6  2021-07-05    MILAN   100
4  2021-07-05       NY   200
7  2021-07-05    PARIS    50
8  2021-07-05  unknown   200
```